# Finding an Eigenvector of $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question $\lambda=4$ find an Eigenvector of a given  $3\times 3$ matrix.

$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
6 & 1& 0 \\
-1 & -2 & -1
\end{array} } \right]
$

I know the answer which is

$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1  \\
-2  \\
-1
\end{array} } \right]
$

But I don't know how to solve it?

The way I tried to do is with RREF but I am not sure how to present it. So can someone help me please

RREF
$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 13 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} } \right]
$

Comment: Do you know how to solve systems of linear equations?

Comment: Your example is discussed in full detail here: http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/eigen2/eigen2.html

Comment: Ya, I do know but I am confused how to solve this question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Pick $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ and solve the system of three equations:
$$Ax=4x$$

Answer (score 0):

you only need to solve $\left(
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & 2 & 1 \\
     6 & 1 & 0 \\
     -1  & -2 & -1
  \end{array} \right) * \left(
  \begin{array}{ c c c }
     u  \\
     v  \\
     w
  \end{array} \right)= \lambda *\left(
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     u \\
     v \\
     w
  \end{array} \right)$